# How to to convert an array from DirectoryIterator into a valid Json format

Tags: php, arrays, json

For testing purpose, i am Looking to convert an array into a valid Json format. To do this, I get a list of files from a directory. This gives me as result:

```
{"data":["file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt"]}
```

Here's my code:

```
public function getDirectories() {
    $dir = $this->getConfig(); // My Directory
    $array = array();
    $handle = opendir($dir);
    while (FALSE !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry == '.' || $entry == '..')
            continue;
        $array[] = $entry;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

And My class for processing:

```
class ArrayValue implements JsonSerializable {

    public function __construct(array $array) {
        $this->array = $array;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return array('data' => $this->array);
    }
}
```

I think I have a here a json result format certainly, but this appears to be invalid, since I have an array in the json.
So How do I proceed to get the following format like this?

```
{"data":{"file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt"}}
```

Comment: You current output is valid json. your expected output is **not**. Dont change anything

Comment: Would `json_encode( array('data' => $array) );` not be simpler?

Answer (score 0):

You first JSON string is fine, since keys of files are numeric, so it's array, and not object.
To simplify everything, you can collect everything to array

```
$data = [
   [
       'data' => [
           'file1.txt',
       ],
       [
           'file2.txt',
       ],

       [
           'file3.txt',
       ],
   ]
];
```

And than just convert array to JSON:

```
$json = json_encode($data);  // will return valid json
$array = json_decode($json); // will return parsed json
```

Comment: I refering to an [example from Zend Framework 2][1] Rest application that will output this result:

Comment: @user1224721 so you are telling that you have basic example from Zend that does not work?

Comment: Yes, it works, but the result I get is identical to what I expect. I'm new to this forum, and it seems complicated post replies. However, here is the link to the example of Rob Allen. https://github.com/akrabat/zf2-api-example

Comment: So if you get correct JSON, than why to create question for that?

Comment: I don't know if it's true or not, I just want to know. Looking at first to get a format that is valid to perform other operations thereafter

Comment: I am going to ask my question in another way, is this format valid, yes or not?
     <!-- language: lang-none -->
    {"1":{"artist":"Bruce Springsteen","title":"High Hopes"},"2":{"artist":"Various","title":"The Trevor Nelson Collection 2"}, .. etc}

Comment: @Antuan yes, it's valid.

Comment: Then why this "{"data":{"file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt"}}", is not. Sorry, this may seem beast as a question, but I would like to start on a good foundation.

Comment: Because file keys are numbers, that is - it's array (marking `[]`). But when you have strings keys, than it's object (making `{}`). Try different php arrays (with keys defined and autokeys) to see difference.

Comment: Ok, I understood. I can not make "$data->(0)", but this "$data->key" is ok. I thank you, I am going to dig this subject.

Comment: @Antuan Please reade more about PHP and JSON. `$data->{0}`, `$data->$key`, `$data->{$this->getId($_POST['username'])}`